# Meaning of ‘NC number’ associated with a gene?‘

Tags: bioinformatics, molecular-genetics, database

Genes in listings etc. often have a number of the type NC_000012.12 associated with them. How should this be interpreted?

Comment: I have edited your question so the title is more useful to others, in view of your original misunderstanding and the correct answer supplied by @JITZ.

Answer (score 4):

This particular ID represent RefSeq accession number.
NC_ stands for a genomic molecule representing complete genomic molecule, usually reference assembly. Every sequence has a stable accession number, a version number, and an integer identifier (gi) assigned to it. RefSeq records can be distinguished from INSDC records by the inclusion of an underscore (“_”) at the third position of the accession number.

Comment: New sequences are no longer being assigned GI numbers ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/news/03-02-2016-phase-out-of-GI-numbers/)) since they were redundant.  Use "accession.version" instead, e.g. "NC_000012.12".